# Debian Jessie stuck at systemd-fsck

Tags: debian, systemd

After updating to Jessie the computer will not boot up.
The boot up stops at **systemd-fsck** each time.

EX:
    [     1.600804] systemd-fsck[194]: /dev/sdb1: clean, 253534/14647296 files, 4095775/58568960 block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to have the same error with Debian Jessie and I obviously was thinking it was a systemd error. In my case it was actually because nouveau was not able to drive my Nvidia GPU, which I guess is the step following disks check in the bootup process. I fixed the error by adding `nomodeset` as a GRUB option, which allowed me launch Gnome and to install Nvidia drivers. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

boot (grub) might hide a *lot* of details, resulting in you thinking your boot *might* be stuck on a fsck. Try to increase grub verbosity and make sure some background network related timeout is not blocking you.

(nothing related to fsck, really)

To increase grub verbosity, edit (e) your linux command line and replace "quiet" with "verbose"